# Best practice for storing settings for a website?

Tags: php, settings

Originally, my intention is to create a class (Object oriented) to store settings as constant. For example, in PHP:

```
class Settings{
     const test = 'foobar!';
}
```

But later on, I think that this approach does not let the Admin user modify these settings. It seems that only non-necessary-to-modify settings should be declared as constant, and others should be declared as private variable, then the application will find whether settings are available in the database Setting table first, if not, it will use default from get(), set() function defined in Settings class. 
Is that a good approach? What is the best approach? I appreciate any pieces advice on this issue.

Comment: My vote is I think this question matters! A well thought out, consistent way to manage your site settings sanely is worth the time to consider.  I've worked with many sites full of globally defined crap being defined all over the place... When you've got a flexible language, you have a responsibility to think out design details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I a prefer similar to your method, but  using a private static property key=>value array with a getter and setter. That way later you can tie them to a file or db.

```
$value = Classname::getparam('configsetting');
Classname::setparam('configsetting', $newvalue);
```

Dont forget to make the get/set param mehods public static!

Here's the full class would look something like...

```
class Classname{
    private static  $params = null;  

    public static function getparam($key){
        if(is_null(self::$params){
             self::$params = array();
             //initialize param array here from file, db, or just hardcoded values...
        }
        return isset(self::$params[$key])?self::$params[$key]:null;
     }

    public static function setparam($key, $value){
        if(is_null(self::$params){
             self::$params = array();
             //initialize array here
        }
        self::$params[$key] = $value;
     }
 }
```

Comment: thks. I've found a really good reference here (specific to Yii framework): http://programmersnotes.info/2009/03/04/handling-application-parameters-in-yii-using-the-database/ 
However, I'll follow your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer :: Your method is fine, its all preference.

Depending on if the settings are going to be changed you may want to look into mysql storage or storing settings to a file, but if they aren't going to be changed your method is fine if thats what your comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider using configuration files in a format such as [YAML](http://yaml.org/).

Comment: And a very [convenient tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.yaml.html) for YAML-configs parsing

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep the settings values that are not necessary to modify as constant and other settings that has the modify option into the database(getter/setter). 
Then I cache the data for a longer period of time so that I dont have to access database for each request. 
When admin changes any settings, cache is invalidated and new value is stored in cache.

There is an another approach of storing settings data in XML files. Can anybody tell me what is the advantage of storing settings data in XML file compared to storing it in database?